# Error in JSON call because of a dotted ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I use an automation in Teamup Calendar. I must fill all fields in the JSON call, but there is a field that make problems ("custom.telefono"). ID's field format is not compatible? Does it happen beacuse of the dot between the two words? I cannot change ID properties, how could I solve that?

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url: "https://api.teamup.com/" + CALENDAR_KEY + "/events",
            type: 'post',
            headers: {
                "Teamup-Token": API_KEY,
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            data: JSON.stringify({
                "title": title,
                "subcalendar_id": subcalendar_id,
                "start_dt": start_dt,
                "end_dt": end_dt,
                "rrule": rrule,
                "all_day": all_day,
                "who": who,
                "location": location,
                "custom.telefono": custom_telefono,  // <- not filling
                "notes": notes
            })
    });

}, false );
```

Comment: What about: `"custom": { "telefono": custom_telefono}`. Also, welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: @Zze thanks for your kind help.. It worked!

Comment: I will post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

JSON field names can definitely contain a dot/period. Object keys are strings in JSON, and strings are defined as follows in the spec (see http://json.org):

> A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes, using backslash escapes.

As you can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fx3vt0wv/1/) on JSFiddle, it works just fine:

```js
var json = JSON.stringify({'custom.telefono': '+1-408-555-1234'});
document.body.innerHTML = json;
```

Are you sure it's not because of the value of that field that you're having issues? What is the actual error you are seeing?

**edit:** looking at the [API docs for TeamUp](http://apidocs.teamup.com/#event-data-structure), it looks like custom fields should be a distinct JSON object, so you should send this:

```js
{
  'title': title,
  'custom': {'telefono': custom_telefono}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can nest objects in your POST method:

```
"custom": { 
   "telefono": custom_telefono
}
```

There is no limit on the complexity of the nested object either. Most API's will expect a level of nesting.